# Como resolver jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'usuario' is undefined

Tags: html, python, mysql, flask

Estoy trabajando un proyecto flask el cual necesita un buscador mediante DNI. Al querer ingresar al template del buscador sale error porque no tiene datos insertados para la búsqueda. Necesito retornar desde la consulta SQL el usuario encontrado y enviarlo al modulo principal y guardarlo como tupla o lista para luego poder mostrar los datos necesarios desde el html.

CODIGO HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% if usuario != False %}
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mt-5">
                    <h1 style="color: #e17d12;">Usuario encontrado.</h1>
                    <h3 style="color: black;">
                        Nombre: <br>{{usuario[1]}}
                    </h3>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('formularioEquipos') }}" class="btn btn-warning" style="text-decoration: underline;" >Cargar datos del equipo</a>
                </div>
            {% else %}
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center mt-5">
                    <h1 style="color: #e17d12;">Usuario no encontrado.</h1>
                    <a href="{{ url_for('newUser') }}" class="btn btn-warning" style="text-decoration: underline;" >Crear Usuario</a>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

PYTHON (MODULO PRINCIPAL)

```
@app.route("/Muestra-Usuarios", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def showUsers():
    user = False
    if request.method == "POST" or request.method == "GET":
        user = conexion.VerUsuarios(request.form['dni'])
        return render_template("VerUsuarios.html", usuario = user) #Muestra el nombre.
```

MODULO PYTHON DE MANEJO DE LA BASE DE DATOS

```
def VerUsuarios(self, dni):
        usuario = aux = None

        self.Conectar()
        cursor = self.__miconexion.cursor()
        
        sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE DNI = `dni`;"
        cursor.execute(sql)
        usuario = list(cursor.fetchall())
        i = 0
        while (i < len(usuario)):
            if (str(dni) != usuario[i][0]):
                print(dni)
                print ("i {}" .format(i))
                print("usuario[{}][0]: {}" .format(i,usuario[i][1]))
                print(usuario[i])
            else:
                aux = usuario[i]
            i += 1

        print("AUX\n{}".format(aux))
            
        self.__miconexion.commit()
        self.CloseConnect()
        return aux
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO

El codigo tenia un error en la condicion de JINJA2.

LINEA DE ERROR.

```
{% if usuario != False %}
```

SOLUCION:

```
{% if usuario %}
```

Esto verifica que sea no nulo, por lo tanto no es necesario colocar operadores.